# Where to place %s in WebDriverWait using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So my python script is supposed to login to a website and wait till the button of the shoe size I set appears so it can click it but where do I place the '% size' using WebdriverWait? Will it go after all 3 parentheses or before all 3 parentheses?

```
size = 9.5
sizeselect = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@data-qa="size-dropdown" and .="%s"]')))
sizeselect.click()
```

so for example will the following code be the right way?

```
size = 9.5
sizeselect = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@data-qa="size-dropdown" and .="%s"]'))) % size
sizeselect.click()
```

or does the % size have to be after the 2nd parentheses

```
size = 9.5
sizeselect = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@data-qa="size-dropdown" and .="%s"]')) % size)
sizeselect.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%s` is some kind of placeholder for exact sub-string you want to pass into string. You should put actual sub-string right after string:

```
"foo %s bar" % "baz"  # "foo baz bar"
```

So in your case it should be

```
sizeselect = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@data-qa="size-dropdown" and .="%s"]' % size)))
```

Similar to *string placeholders* is `format()`:

```
"foo {} bar".format("baz")  # "foo baz bar"
```

In your case

```
sizeselect = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@data-qa="size-dropdown" and .="{}"]'.format(size))))
```

You can check more about string formatting [here](https://pyformat.info/)

Answer (score 0):

As you need to invoke `click()` on the *shoe size* instead of using the `expected_conditions` as `presence_of_element_located` you need to use **`element_to_be_clickable`** as follows:

- Using the *absolute value*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-qa="size-dropdown" and contains(.,'9.5')]"))).click()
  ```
- Using a *variable*:

  ```
  size = 9.5
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-qa="size-dropdown"][.='" + size + "']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `%s`:

  ```
  size = 9.5
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-qa="size-dropdown and contains(text(), '%s')]" % (size)))).click()
  ```
- Using `format()`:

  ```
  size = 9.5
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@data-qa="size-dropdown and contains(text(), "{}")]'.format(size))))).click()
  ```